# In mini-batch gradient descent, are the weights updated after each batch or after all the batches have gone through an epoch?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, gradient-descent, weights, mini-batch-gradient-descent

Say I have a mini-batch of size 32, and I have 10 such batches. Assuming I only run it for one epoch (just for the sake of understanding it), Will the weights be updated using the gradients of one mini-batch, or will it be done after all the 10 mini batches have passed through?

Intuitively for me, it ought to be the first one because otherwise, the only difference between Batch-GD and mini-batch GD will be the size of the batch.

Comment: In one epoch, weights will be updated 10 times for the above case.

Comment: Thanks, such a silly thing but it was bothering a lot.

Comment: What @SwaksharDeb says is correct. There are 10 batches, so 10 updates. There are 32 data points in each batch but each batch produces a single aggregate (or mean) error on the 32 data points so a single gradient is produced making a single update to the parameter values.